# NSXMLParser problem

Tags: xml, ios, parsing

I don't know how to use NSXMLParser. I have this xml from a server and I need the user id message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response value="1">
    <user id="100">
    <field name="name">DATO</field>
    <field name="lastname">DATO</field>
    <field name="country">DATO</field>
    <field name="usstate">DATO</field>
    <field name="email">DATO</field>

    </user>
    <message>Login successfully</message>
    </response>
```

I got this far

```
 NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myResult];
[parser setDelegate:self]; // The parser calls methods in this class
[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; // We don't care about namespaces
[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; //
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; // We just want data, no other stuff

[parser parse]; // Parse that data..
[parser release];
```

And implemented this metod:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
//NSLog(@"user");
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"user"])
{
    NSLog(@"user");
    //NSString(@"");
}
}
```

I know it is easy but I can't find the answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the id can be found in the attributeDict that is passed in to the parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes: method.  To access the value of the id attribute, this should work:

```
[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"]
```